# GWT: IE problem

Tags: firefox, gwt

Element tdElement = (Element)leftContentPanel.getElement().getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0);
tdElement.setAttribute("style", "vertical-align: top; width:100%;");

tdElement.getAttribute("style") returns :
[object CSSStyleDeclaration]  >>> ON IE 
"width:100%;..." ON FF

Doesn't work on IE why???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use element.getStyle() that returns a Style object.

Ex:

```
Element tdElement = (Element)leftContentPanel.getElement().getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0);
        tdElement.getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PCT);
```